# SQL UPDATE 'The Column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'a'

Tags: sql, linked-server

I am fairly new to SQL and I'm having trouble finding out how to fix this error.  I understand that I'll get the error because I'm pulling the same column name twice from the same table, so I've created different aliases for the tables.
What I am trying to do is update a table in my database using a query to pull data from a linked server.

Here is a sample:

```
UPDATE [Database].dbo.T1 
SET 
    T1.Status = item.Status,
    T1.CategoryA = c.DESC_TEXT,
    T1.CategoryB = d.DESC_TEXT
FROM
(SELECT c.DESC_TEXT, d.DESC_TEXT
    inner join CSM_CODE c ON c.DESC_CD = item.ParCat and c.DESC_TYPE = 'PARCAT'
    inner join CSM_CODE d ON d.DESC_CD = item.ChCat and d.DESC_TYPE = 'CHCAT'
WHERE
    T1.Status = 'NEW')) A

WHERE [Database].dbo.T1.ID = A.ID
```

Here is my exact error:

The column 'DESC_TEXT' was specified multiple times for 'A'

So I don't know what to do about the aliases in my subquery for this update. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, your code makes no sense.

Comment: I see why it doesn't make sense. you are right.  It's backwards.  That's what I get to rushing into my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping figure this out.  I now know why I was still receiving errors.  Once I created the alias within my sub query, I had failed to update that alias in the SET.

```
UPDATE [database].dbo.T1
SET
    [STATUS] = A.[STATUS],
    [Scrum Team] = A.team_name, 
    [Parent Category] = A.prodparcat,
    [Child Category] = A.prodcat
FROM
    (SELECT 
     item.SEQ_ID,
    item.STATUS,
    c.DESC_TEXT prodparcat,
    d.DESC_TEXT prodcat
FROM item
    inner join csm_code c ON c.DESC_CD = item.parent_cat_cd and c.DESC_TYPE = 'PRODPARCAT'
    inner join CSM_CODE d ON d.DESC_CD = item.prod_cat and d.DESC_TYPE = 'PRODCAT'
WHERE

item.STATUS = 'NEW' ) A
WHERE
    [database.dbo.T1.[external ID] = A.SEQ_ID
```

It's also important to note that I was querying a linked server which required some creativity with my alias.  Overall a great learning experience.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have specified DESC_TEST twice with

```
c.DESC_TEXT, d.DESC_TEXT
```

Try renaming to.

```
c.DESC_TEXT category_a , d.DESC_TEXT category_b
```

You'll also need an id in A to join on.

An example to give you an idea.

```
UPDATE [Database].dbo.T1 
SET 
    T1.Status = A.Status,
    T1.CategoryA = A.CategoryA,
    T1.CategoryB = A.CategoryB
FROM
(SELECT item.status, c.id, c.DESC_TEXT CategoryA, d.DESC_TEXT CategoryB
    from item -- added after seeing the answer.
    inner join CSM_CODE c ON c.DESC_CD = item.ParCat and c.DESC_TYPE = 'PARCAT'
    inner join CSM_CODE d ON d.DESC_CD = item.ChCat and d.DESC_TYPE = 'CHCAT'
WHERE
    T1.Status = 'NEW')) A

WHERE [Database].dbo.T1.ID = A.ID
```

Untested

Comment: Looks like this should work. The SQL recognized the column alias in the SET statement, but now I'm getting "could not be bound" errors for the entire subquery

Comment: Try running the inner query and see what sort of results you're getting.

Comment: I get the results that I need. The ones I need to use to update the table.  The sub query works.

Comment: So where does item.status come from ... that would be the issue.

Comment: I changed the answer to guess where status came from.

Comment: posted my answer.  Learned a bunch with this hurdle!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `FROM` it should be a `update-join` construct like below. Also use column alias name for the duplicated columns.

```
UPDATE [Database].dbo.T1 
SET 
    T1.Status = item.Status,
    T1.CategoryA = A.cdesk,
    T1.CategoryB = A.ddesk
JOIN
(SELECT c.DESC_TEXT as cdesk, d.DESC_TEXT as ddesk
 FROM item
 inner join CSM_CODE c ON c.DESC_CD = item.ParCat and c.DESC_TYPE = 'PARCAT'
inner join CSM_CODE d ON d.DESC_CD = item.ChCat and d.DESC_TYPE = 'CHCAT'
WHERE T1.Status = 'NEW')) A    
ON [Database].dbo.T1.ID = A.ID
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining a column named DESC_TEXT from two different tables into a single table, namely A in your case. In that case, you have to give these two columns different names, like DESC_TEXT_c and DESC_TEXT_d and update T1 accordingly.

Comment: That's because when you SET during UPDATE, you do not need to mention the table name of the column that you are trying to update. Refer to Gordon Linoff's answer, his answer corrects for that error. To be specific, you only need names of the columns on which you seek to SET values in the SET clause. However, when you want to call on these columns outside of the SET clause, you will need to attach "T1." to the front.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
UPDATE T1 
    SET Status = item.Status,
        CategoryA = c.DESC_TEXT,
        CategoryB = d.DESC_TEXT
    FROM [Database].dbo.T1 T1 JOIN
         CSM_CODE c
         ON c.DESC_CD = T1.ParCat and c.DESC_TYPE = 'PARCAT' JOIN
         CSM_CODE d
         ON d.DESC_CD = item.ChCat and d.DESC_TYPE = 'CHCAT'
    WHERE T1.Status = 'NEW';
```

As written, your code has multiple syntax errors.  The two references to `DESC_TEXT` in the subquery are the tip of the iceberg.  I believe the above is the logic you want.

Comment: You've left out the sub query which is needed to get the data from the linked server.

Comment: @LDag0507 . . . `[Database].dbo.T1` is in the `FROM`  clause.